# SQLCL console print to file instead of stdout

Tags: oracle, sqlcl

I have a .bat file which looks like this:

```
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql javi/pwd@tnsname @"mypath1"
```

The script it calls looks like this:

```
select 1 from dual;
select 2 from dual;
exit;
```

Is there any way to log everything in the cmd and the sqlcl console into a file instead/in addition to being printed in stdout?

I have tried the below, but it creates an empty log file:

```
start C:\sqlcl-latest\sqlcl\bin\sql javi/pwd@tnsname @"mypath1" > mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have SQLCL, but this (**redirection to file**) should (at least, I hope so) work at operating system command prompt.

myfile1.sql:

```
select * from dept;
```

myfile2.sql:

```
select empno, ename, job, sal
from emp
where deptno = 10;
```

mypath1.sql:

```
@"myfile1"
@"myfile2"
exit;
```

mybat.bat:

```
sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl@mypath1.sql > mylog.txt
                                     -----------
                                     this redirects output into mylog.txt file
```

---

Running the `mybat.bat` at the command prompt:

```
C:\>mybat

C:\>sqlplus scott/tiger@orcl@mypath1.sql  1>mylog.txt
```

There's no output to screen; everything is contained in `mylog.txt` file so - let's check it:

```
C:\>type mylog.txt

SQL*Plus: Release 18.0.0.0.0 - Production on Čet Sij 19 08:18:58 2023
Version 18.5.0.0.0

Copyright (c) 1982, 2018, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

Active code page: 1250


    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO
        40 OPERATIONS     BOSTON


     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              SAL
---------- ---------- --------- ----------
      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         2450
      7839 KING       PRESIDENT       5000
      7934 MILLER     CLERK           1300

Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

C:\>
```

Comment: I have tried the > log.txt at the end of my line in the command prompt, but it creates an empty log file. I have edited the question for more clarity.